# Passport deserializing multiple times on login

Tags: node.js, passport.js

The issue is when I log in, passport will run its deserialize function a good number of times. While this isn't having any effect on things, that I know of. Having it do this could be problematic later on down the road. 
Here is the logs:

```
Bloodmorphed has been Serialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
```

Here is the passport:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
let io = require('./io');

module.exports = (passport) => {

  // =========================================================================
  // passport session setup ==================================================
  // =========================================================================

  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(user.username + ' has been Serialized');
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users, users_meta WHERE users.id = ? AND users_meta.id =?';
    db.query(sql, [id, id]).then(results => {
      var userdata = results[0];
      console.log(userdata.username + ' has been deserialized');
      done(null, userdata);
    });
  });

  // Local Strategy login
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
  }, (req, username, password, done) => {
    // Match Username
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    db.query(sql, [username]).then(results => {
      if (!results.length) {
        return done(null, false, {
          type: 'loginMessage',
          message: 'Wrong Login',
        });
      }

      //  Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (isMatch) {
          var userData = results[0];
          sql = 'SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE id = ?';
          db.query(sql, userData.id).then(results => {
            Object.assign(userData, results[0]);
            return done(null, userData);
          });

        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            type: 'loginMessage',
            message: 'Wrong Login',
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
};
```

While this is not a high priority issue as of now, I would like to get it fixed, or if it is indeed normal for the to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/14#issuecomment-4863459

The serving of static files should be done before `passport.session`.

For instance, according to the refereed source:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  // passport session is triggered, causing deserializeUser to be invoked
  app.use(passport.session());
  // but request was for a static asset, for which authentication is not
  // necessary
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
});
```

Should be changed to:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.logger())
  // requests for static assets will be handled immediately and will not continue
  // down the middleware stack
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
  // any request that gets here is a dynamic page, and benefits from session
  // support
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
});
```

Comment: I do do that, theres only a select few things I do before my static file setting.

Answer (score -1):

If memory serves correct, Passport deserializes on every request. Because the session key is stored in a cookie on the user's browser.

From the [PassportJS documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/):

> In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a
>   user will only be transmitted during the login request. If
>   authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained
>   via a cookie set in the user's browser.
>
> Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the
>   unique cookie that identifies the session. In order to support login
>   sessions, Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to
>   and from the session.

Comment: Ah okay, but it is weird that it did it so many times on login itself. There should be only one instance during login, unless me passing it through an io channel counts as well.